# Partitioning element

Tags: algorithm, partitioning

im trying to understand the below text:

You are given a list and it has just been partitioned using a standard partitioning algorithm. You are to say which element could have been the partitioning element. For example, given the numbers [7, 6, 8, 20, 11, 5, 14], then only 8 could have been the partitioning element and the algorithm will continue sorting [7, 6] and [20, 11, 5, 14].

im trying to understand how 8 is the partitioning element here? Thanks

Comment: Where does this come from? What is called a "standard partitioning algorithm"?

Comment: It's part of a section on quicksort

Comment: If it is an iteration of quicksort and 8 is the pivot, 5 should not be on the right after the iteration. So this must be a typo.

Comment: so then in this list [2, 4, 8, 6, 18, 14, 20, 22, 18] , it should be what?

Comment: Your input is wrong: 8 cannot be the partitioning element since {all in left set} < 8 < {all in right set}. This is not true since 5 (from your right set) < 8.  I don't think any element is a partitioning element from your example

Comment: @Pab If it's *after* a quicksort iteration, it could either be 2 or 4. Either one could have led to this configuration, but there's no way to tell which one for sure.

Comment: Thanks patrice , it was both 2 and 4 , could you quickly explain how you got 2 and 4? Thanks

Comment: I suggest: 1. Read about quicksort and its partitioning 2. Check your data since it doesn't make sense for 8 to be a pivot element in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of a quicksort iteration, every element to the left of the pivot p (partitioning element) must be lesser than p, and every element to the right must be greater than p. This means that p is now at its final sorted position. The quicksort algorithm proceeds recursively on both resulting subarrays (left and right).

Given a configuration of the array during the quicksort process, you can identify the possible pivots that could have been used on the previous iteration with this simple quadratic procedure:

```
foreach int m in the array
  if (all int l on the left of m verify l < m)
    AND (all int r on the right of m verify r >= m)
  then
    m was a possible pivot in the previous iteration
```

You can do better than O(n^2), but this is the basic idea.